# How to place variable name instead of direct values in json_array_push_json in single store query?

Tags: java, json, singlestore

In this query I have given the dummy values and it is working fine in single store

```
String cucpcelllocalidUpdate = "UPDATE deviceconfig SET operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells = "
                + "JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_JSON(operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells, '{\"cell_id\" : \"cellindex_1\",\"cucp_cell_localid\":\"23\"}') "
                + "where device_config_id = :deviceconfigid";
```

I am getting output as:
"cells": [{
"cell_id": "cellindex_1",
"cucp_cell_localid": "23"
}]

When I try to replace the dummy values with variables, I am finding difficulty in the syntax for placing the varibles

I want to give cellindex(variable name) instead of cellindex_1(value)  and celllocaid (variable name) instead of 23(value)

```
String cucpcelllocalidUpdate = "UPDATE deviceconfig SET operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells = "
            + " JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_JSON(operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells, '{\"cell_id\":\":cellindex\", \"cucp_cell_localid\":\":celllocalid\"}') "
            + " where device_config_id = :deviceconfigid";
```

I have also tried like this:

```
String cucpcelllocalidUpdate = "UPDATE deviceconfig SET operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells = "
                + " JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_JSON(operator_rw_config\\:\\:cells, '{\"cell_id\":\""+cellindex+"\", \"cucp_cell_localid\":\""+celllocalid+"\"}') "
                + " where device_config_id = :deviceconfigid";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is from the generated string in java.
Your variable cucpcelllocalidUpdate is equal to :

```
UPDATE deviceconfig SET operator_rw_config\:\:cells =  JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_JSON(operator_rw_config\:\:cells, '{"cell_id":"cellindex_1", "cucp_cell_localid":"23"}')  where device_config_id = :deviceconfigid
```

It's not recognize in SingleStore because of operator_rw_config\:\:cells , this should correct your SQL query :

```
String cucpcelllocalidUpdate = "UPDATE deviceconfig SET operator_rw_config::cells = "
                + " JSON_ARRAY_PUSH_JSON(operator_rw_config::cells, '{\"cell_id\":\""+cellindex+"\", \"cucp_cell_localid\":\""+celllocalid+"\"}') "
                + " where device_config_id = :deviceconfigid";
```

I also realised that there is this value :deviceconfigid , you might change it with a plain value or concat the string with a variable.